How do you say "wavy hair" in Chinese?
Adjective

波浪形 = wave-shaped

鬈 = 波浪形；有弯曲（？）
(For this, I was uncertain, as the word "鬈" alone just has the definition of "fine" or "beautiful" hair.



Noun
As a noun, I am wondering if "鬈发" is a good translation. I couldn't find it on online dictionaries, but was able to find it by chance through a book.
When you add the character for "发" after "鬈", its definition becomes...
→
鬈发 = wavy hair; hair that has some curl texture in it（鬈曲的头发）
For example:

他顶着微鬈的长发 （He has a lightly wavy long hair.)


Simple way to look at it
Straight hair = 直髮

wavy hair/ curvy hair = 波浪形頭髮/ 曲髮

curly hair = 捲髮

Using 髮捲 (Curls) to make 捲髮 (curly hair)

捲髮 = 鬈髮

There are almost always more ways than one of expressing something!
Goldilocks: 金发姑娘 (三只熊) had straight hair (at least in Disney films), maybe she was named after the flower? 《金凤花姑娘》
卷发：形状呈卷曲的头发。curly hair or curl hair, ringlets, locks, frizzy hair
卷发：指头发因过度干燥或湿度过高而变得蓬松、卷曲、难以控制的状态。frizzy hair
她拥有一头波浪形的长发。
She has a head full of long wavy hair.
有的人长着天然卷发。
Some people have naturally frizzy hair.
要卷发要吃卷饼!

Goldilocks is thus named because she has golden locks, which just means golden hair, regardless of whether it’s straight, wavy or curly.

The 3 Bears told me she had wavy hair! 三只熊是骗子呀！ I don't know about you, but I would never refer to straight hair as locks. For me, locks are curls! I suppose I get that from the German version of Silent Night: "Holde Knabe im lockig'n Haar!" But, a straight line is part of a circle with infinite radius, you could be right!

Yes, lockig in German is unambiguously curly, and if you talk about a singular lock of hair, that at least somewhat implies that it’s not just plain, straight hair. But in the plural, it just refers to a head of hair of any type, and you can find lots of examples of phrases like “her long, straight locks” in use.
